# Sum column and add result to dataframe in R

Tags: r, for-loop, sum

I currently have a dataframe in R that contains one variable with a unique identifier, and several variables of that contain simply binary responses (0 or 1).

A simplified version of my dataframe with two example rows:

```
c.names <- c("ID", "male", "female")
df <- c("ADH0004", 0, 1,
        "ADH0005", 1, 0)
df <- matrix(df, nrow = 2, byrow = T)
df <- as.data.frame(df)
names(df) <- c.names
df
```

In my final dataframe I will have potentially several hundred variables, all binary. I want to find a way to:

1. obtain the column sum for each variable, and
2. assign the column sum (1.) to a new variable (with the total copied in to each row)
3. repeat this over each variable, so that I have n variables, and the same number of new variables with the totals in.

Returning to my simple dataframe example, my new dataframe would look like:

```
c.names <- c("ID", "male", "female", "male_t", "female_t")
df <- c("ADH0004", 0, 1, 1, 1,
        "ADH0005", 1, 0, 1, 1)
df <- matrix(df, nrow = 2, byrow = T)
df <- as.data.frame(df)
names(df) <- c.names
df
```

To do this for one variable at a time is easy (even for me). I would simply:

```
df$male_t <- sum(df$male)
```

I could do this for each variable manually, but I expect I could end up with up to a hundred, so I want to loop over this. I don't mind using a for loop (rather than apply) if that's easier, because I have a relatively small number of loops to do, so ease of coding is more of a priority than absolute speed of the code. Nevertheless I've tried both apply and for approaches.

for:

```
varlist <- c("male", female")
for (i in varlist) {
  df$i_t <- df$i
}
```

(I've tried here to emulate a for loop I saw in Stata, where the total variables are generated with `i'_t, but this doesn't seem to work in R.

I've also tried apply:

```
apply(df[c("male", "female")], MARGIN = 2, sum)
```

This gets me closer to my desired outcome, but I don't know how to save the column sums in the dataframe as new columns, rather than simply outputted to the console as they are now.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, naturally I've looked extensively on both stackoverflow and the wider internet.
Phil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
   for(var in colnames(df)[-1]) {
     df[[paste0(var, '_t')]] <- sum(df[[var]])
   }
```

Comment: With a small edit, that worked, thank you! I needed to exclude the first column by specifying only columns 2 and 3: for(var in colnames(df[, 2:3])){..., otherwise it tried and failed to add the IDs.

Answer (score 2):

```
# Your columns 2 & 3 are character - convert to numeric
df[,2:3] <- sapply(df[,2:3] , as.numeric)

# Get column totals for all variables except the first
c <- colSums(df[-1])

# Add to df:  c is transposed so is added as columns
# values of c are recycled, so added to all rows of df
df <- data.frame(df , t(c))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The last line doesn't seem to add the columns to the dataframe, it just produces the output in console. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: That's worked, thank you. I have the right number of 'total' variables, which can be easily renamed with names(df) <- c("...")

Comment: You can use regex for the names - save typing. `names(df) <- gsub("\\.1" , "_t" , names(df))`

Answer (score 0):

This your dataframe df is full of factors. So I chose 2 varibales male and female and convert them to the numeric

```
df[,c(2,3)] <- apply(df[,c(2,3)],2,as.numeric)
```

then sum these two variables

```
cbind(df,as.data.frame(t(colSums(df[,c(2,3)])))) # Is it right result???
```